# How do I integrate from power and exponential functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to solve the following integral

$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{m\left(m + 1\right)/2\ +\ 1}
\prod_{i\ =\ 1}^{m}\,\exp\left(-b_{i}\,x^{i}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x,
$$

where $b_{i} > 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq m$. I tried using partial functions but that didn't lead to anything.

Any suggestion ?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, not an answer
(meaning that I hope that
it might help someone else
come up with an answer).

$\begin{array}\\
f_m
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{m\left(m + 1\right)/2\ +\ 1}
\prod_{i\ =\ 1}^{m}\,\exp\left(-b_{i}\,x^{i}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{1+\sum_{i=1}^m i}
\prod_{i\ =\ 1}^{m}\,\exp\left(-b_{i}\,x^{i}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_{1}^{\infty}x
\prod_{i\ =\ 1}^{m}\,x^i\exp\left(-b_{i}\,x^{i}\right)\,dx\\
\end{array}
$